# How to resolve "target does not implement selector" this exception when use NSThread spawn thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I am a pretty new in use `NSThread` to spawn thread. In my practise, I want to spawn a thread to execute a method that print a String in `CreateThread` Class. But when I run my program, "target does not implement selector" exception is displayed in the console. How I should to be done in order to resolve this problem? Thanks for answer.

Code below:

```
import Foundation

class CreateThread {

func HelloWorld() {

    print("Hello World!")

    NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector("secondaryThreadMethod", toTarget: self, withObject: nil)

    print("Test")

}

func secondaryThreadMethod() {

    print("Hello World in Secondary Thread!")

}

}

let createThread = CreateThread()
createThread.HelloWorld()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NSThread api operates in objective-c runtime and your CreateThread class is pure swift - by default its methods are not visible in objective-c world. To solve that you can make your class inherit from NSObject or mark your secondaryThreadMethod method as `@objc`:

```
// Either of following lines will fix the crash
class CreateThread : NSObject {
...
@objc func secondaryThreadMethod() {
```

You can read more about swift and objective-c interoperability in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/)

Comment: You didn't actually change the class declaration.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks to solve this question for me! I wonder if you have a bit time for help me solve another question that why does not the `secondaryThreadMethod` method output **"Hello World in Secondary Thread!"** in the secondary thread?

Comment: Hi @KenThomases, I wonder if you have a bit time for help me solve another question that why does not the `secondaryThreadMethod` method output **"Hello World in Secondary Thread!"** in the secondary thread? Thanks!

Comment: @Sherlock, the program is exiting before the secondary thread has a chance to do anything. If this is a playground, you can import `XCPlayground` and set `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`. Otherwise, you need to keep the main thread around somehow so the program doesn't exit.

Comment: @KenThomases, I got you, Because the main thread exit very fast and does not wait the secondary thread, so that the secondary thread has no chance to perform `secondaryThreadMethod`. I add the `sleep(5)` above `print("Test")`, it does work! Thanks again!